# Excel VBA onChange Event

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to fire an onChange event when value entered to column A.

Now I want this, if I enter any value from Column A to Column AS, the event will fire and if I remove any value from same columns it will work as Code is written.

Also if I copy and paste a multiple data it's not working, also if I'm removing the multiple data it's not working.

Can anyone help on this? Below is the code.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim currentRow As Integer

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then

        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            currentRow = Target.Row
            Target.Parent.Range("A" & currentRow & ":AS" & currentRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
            Target.Parent.Range("A" & currentRow & ":AS" & currentRow).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End If

        If Target.Value = "" Then
            currentRow = Target.Row
            Target.Parent.Range("A" & currentRow & ":AS" & currentRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            Target.Parent.Range("A" & currentRow & ":AS" & currentRow).Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Selecting multiple cells will mean `Target.Value` is an array.  `If Target.Value = "" Then` will always be false when Target is an array.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: One continuous block

Comment: As a side note, use `Cell`s arguments instead of constructing range address from string:`With Target.Parent: .Range(.Cells(currentRow,  "A"), .Cells(currentRow, "AS")): End With`. This is more readable. Or: `Target.Parent.Cells(currentRow, "A").Resize(, 19)`. This is more concise! 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Target.Value` only has a value if a single cell is selected.  If you select more than one cell it becomes an array and your `If` statement will always evaluate to `False`.

Here is one way to change your code.  I was in a bit of a hurry so it could probably be done much better but should get you started.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Target) = 0 Then
            ' Empty Range
            For Each rw In Target.Rows
                Target.Parent.Range("A" & rw.Row & ":AS" & rw.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                Target.Parent.Range("A" & rw.Row & ":AS" & rw.Row).Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
            Next rw
        Else
            ' Not Empty
            For Each rw In Target.Rows
                Target.Parent.Range("A" & rw.Row & ":AS" & rw.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                Target.Parent.Range("A" & rw.Row & ":AS" & rw.Row).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            Next rw
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```